# R - Combine data from different urls

Tags: r, json, dataframe, loops

With the next code I import data in JSON format from two different urls and then I combine them to get an unique dataframe:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

url1 <- 'https://c.stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=perf&group=SECTOR_DJUSOI'
document1<-na.omit(select(fromJSON(url1),Ticker=sym,Name=name,SCTR=sctr,Capital=univ))
document1$SubSector="DJUSOI"

url2 <- 'https://c.stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=perf&group=SECTOR_DJUSOL'
document2<-na.omit(select(fromJSON(url2),Ticker=sym,Name=name,SCTR=sctr,Capital=univ))
document2$SubSector="DJUSOL"

#Combined file
USA<-rbind.data.frame(document1,document2)
```

My problem is that I need to import data from more than 100 different urls, so I assume I should use a loop. The only thing that changes at each url is the sector name (after the underscore): DJUSOI, DJUSOL, etc.

Could somebody let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only thing that really changes is the sector name, I think this should work for you:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

DownloadSubSec = function(sector) {
  url = 'https://c.stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=perf&group=SECTOR_'
  url = paste0(url, sector)
  doc = na.omit(select(fromJSON(url), Ticker = sym, Name = name,
                       SCTR = sctr, Capital = univ))
  doc$SubSector = sector
  return(doc)
}

sector_names = c('DJUSOI', 'DJUSOL')
usa = sector_names %>%
  lapply(DownloadSubSec) %>%
  bind_rows
```

Comment: Thank you rodolfo. I get the error "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400."

Comment: i'm sorry @CarlosFC, i used **paste** instead of **paste0**.. **paste** add a space between the strings, that's why you've an error. i just updated a new code chunk and it's running smoothly now. let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much rodolfo!. It works perfect now. Could you please explain what the function lapply does here?

Comment: Sure @CarlosFC. **lapply()** is a shorter and more efficient way to do **for** loops in R. The first argument of **lapply()** is the vector to loop on and the second argument is the function to apply . Since I'm using pipes from **dplyr** package, the statement **sector_names %>% lapply(DownloadSubSec)** is the same as **lapply(sector_names, DownloadSubSec)**, which means I get each value of the vector **sector_names** and use as the first argument of **DownloadSubSec()**. For more about **lapply()** you access [https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html]. I hope I was clear!

Comment: Thank you so much Rodolfo. I will try to learn more about this function...

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop. You can add the sectors you want to `sectors` vector:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

sectors <- c('DJUSOI', 'DJUSOL')

documents <- data.frame()
for (sector in sectors){
  url <- paste0('https://c.stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=perf&group=SECTOR_', sector)
  current <- fromJSON(url) %>% 
    select(Ticker=sym,Name=name,SCTR=sctr,Capital=univ) %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate(SubSector = sector)
  documents <- bind_rows(documents, current)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza. It works perfect. I have just added na.omit before fromJSON to avoid NA. Just a question. In order to avoid toO much text, how could I use just sector name (DJUSOI,DJUSOL.

Comment: I just modified the answer. is that what you need?

Comment: Yes Reza. Perfect! Thanks a lot.